# How to correctly create an If/Else statement using Handlebars.JS?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a button which depending on whether the text input it triggers is opened or not, switches between 'Report A Problem' to 'Close'. In an effort to consolidate my code I've decided to use [Handlebars.JS](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#simple-expressions) to create the following:

```
  <button id="myBtnToReportABug" onclick="toggleReportForm(); clearFields();" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" >{{#if report_form_opened}} Report A Problem {{else}} Close {{/if}}</button>
```

I've followed examples in the documentation, and as you can see in the Javascript I will attach below, I have a functioning toggle on togggleReportForm, which console logs true & false upon each click. I'm not sure what I'm missing here and would appreciate any tips.

Currently the button only displays 'Close' with no error messages.

```
var report_form_opened = report_form_opened;
 $(document).ready(function() {
  const client = ZAFClient.init();
  
         $("#myBtnToReportABug").click(() => collapse.collapse('toggle'));


          $("#bugForm").submit((e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const input = document.getElementById('nameInput');
            bugInfo = {
              "name": "Report From " + idTicket,
              "story_type" : "Bug",
              "description": input.value + " " + `${data.ticket.brand.url}/agent/tickets/${idTicket}`,
            }
            reportBug(bugInfo).then(collapse.collapse('toggle'))
          })
        });
      });
    });



    async function reportBug(data = {}) {
      const url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/2530461/stories'
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "X-TrackerToken": `${metadata.settings.token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
      return response.json();
    }


// changes text on 'report problem' button when form open
function toggleReportForm() {
  report_form_opened = !report_form_opened;
  console.log(toggleReportForm)
}

// clears text field onclick
function clearFields() {
  document.getElementById("nameInput").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Your script does not contain a single console.log command, you also forgot to mention what the problem is with your code. Please 1. describe the expected behavior and what you're getting instead 2. be specific 3. mention error messages you're getting if any and 4. remove irrelevant code from your question

Comment: @ChrisG I'm aware it doesn't contain console.log, I remove those before posting. What does it provide to the question? Happy to update with them in future." I have a button which depending on whether the text input it triggers is opened or not, switches between 'Report A Problem' to 'Close'. " is my expected behaviour. I'm not receiving any error messages, however the button is always displaying the 'Close' aka else statement. thanks for the tips

Comment: It provides that the OP is capable of doing basic debugging. Anyway, are you actually updating the DOM after the change? I imagine changing the variable is not enough; handlebar has no idea that the value was changed so it wouldn't know to update the button even if it worked like that

Comment: I don't see where you are rendering your template. As @ChrisG has mentioned above, you will need to re-render your template when you have a different value for `report_form_opened`. Handlebars is not reactive - it is not listening for changes to the underlying data and re-rendering when they occur.